# Accessing files/directories in 'lost+found' following fsck of partially-dd'ed-over EXT4 filesystem

Tags: dd, ext4, fsck

I'm trying to recover data from a 3TB EXT4 partition in an LVM setup of which I hosed the first ~1GB with `dd` and am having trouble accessing files which have been placed in `lost+found` due to permissions issues.

Some background:

I've successfully recovered the LVM metadata using the files in `/etc/lvm/backup` and `/etc/lvm/archive`.

Once the metadata was back in place I used `mkfs.ext4 -n -m0` (`-m0` being the only parameter passed when the filesystem was initially created) to find the locations of the backup superblocks and then ran `fsck` specifying the backup superblock nearest the end of the partition (`fsck.ext4 -b $LAST_SUPERBLOCK_OF_PARTITION -y /dev/vg/lv`).

Once this was done, I tried another run of `fsck` to see if I could get it to a point where it reported no modifications to the filesystem, to no avail. Figuring that nothing was going to change, I mounted the partition, opened my file manager as root and started to attempt to peruse `lost+found` to see what had been recovered.

[image: screenshot]

As can be seen from the screenshot the modification and access timestamps are completely messed up, as are the users and groups. I am able to enter the directories shown as containing 0 items (`oppføringer`), but for those listed with a question mark I get a

> you do not have the permissions to access…

message. On a whim, I tried `sudo chown -Rv root:root <mount point>/lost+found/` and familiar file and directory names started scrolling past, but with 'permission denied' messages (which I found odd given that I was root).

Does anyone have any pointers as to how I can attempt further access/recovery?